How to dynamically reference text in a table in a formula
I have two tables:
project_dashboard is an overview of all my planned, ongoing and completed projects
and
project_1 is a summary of all steps it took to complete 1 specific project and amount they cost
Now what I want to do is to SUMIFS the cost entered in table project_1 into table project_dashboard for a quick overview
BUT
there will be tens of project in the future and I want one formula to dynamically calculate the cost of all the projects individually based on the project name which is the same as the table project_1
---Name ------------- Cost
project_1-------SUMIFS(project_1[Price], project_1[Status], "Completed")
project_2-------SUMIFS(project_2[Price], project_2[Status], "Completed")
I tried INDIRECT but i wasn't able to make it work with the table :(

You could try using the following formula:


=SUMIFS(
    INDIRECT(
        [@NAME] & "[Price]"
    ),
    INDIRECT(
        [@NAME] & "[Status]"
    ), "Completed"
)


